# How to join in swarm using the tutorial, Hyperledger fabric on multiple hosts by wahab

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the tutorial:
https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f
We are struck on some point,

My doubts are:

1. "docker swarm init" command need to execute in both PC's or only in PC1.
2. After executing "docker swarm join-token manager" command in PC1, it produce output like
   docker swarm join — token SWMTKN-1–3as8cvf3yxk8e7zj98954jhjza3w75mngmxh543llgpo0c8k7z-61zyibtaqjjimkqj8p6t9lwgu 172.16.0.153:2377
3. We copy it and execute it on PC2 terminal to make it join PC1,
   In this step we are getting error like: Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.
4. If we try to execute "docker swarm join" another time, it is showing error like: Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
5. If we leave and try to connect docker swarm again, still problem continue like Timeout reached before joined.
6. Now shall we proceed on PC1 even above error is present or shall we have to wait until PC2 joins in swarm.
7. How to solve the above problem.

   In our case, PC2 running ubuntu on Windows using VMVirtualBox. Is it any problem for our error.
   We tried to solve the problem by opening up port numbers and enabling firewall also. But we did not succeed.

Kindly suggest me to solve this problem.

Comment: Although your final target is to build a Fabric network, this question is not related at all with Fabric. Consider to re-tag it as Docker-Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

Check my article on medium

Hyperledger Fabric with kafka, Zookeeper and swarm cluster For → Multi Orgs & Multi Nodes Setup

https://link.medium.com/n3H9ShA4f1

Answer (score 0):

Answers for your questions:

1) No. No need to Swarm init in both the PCs. PC1 alone needs to be initialized.
For the further steps to function make sure that all your PCs are in the same network. I mean in the same internet connection.

If you want to join all PCs accross different network then go through --listen-addr & --advertise-addr in docker swarm.